# throw inside a promise crashes server

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, babeljs

here is a piece of code that should work perfectly as per my knowledge, but is crashing the server

**note**: I'm using ES6 with babel

```
const getDataFromCouchBase = function (siteId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const cluster = new couchbase.Cluster('127.0.0.1:8091'),
            bucket = cluster.openBucket(bucketName, (err) => {
                console.log("err: ", err);
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                    //reject(err);
                }

                // Retrieve a document
                bucket.get(`site::${siteId}`, (err, result) => {
                    console.log("err: ", err);
                    console.log("result: ", result);
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                        //reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(result.value);
                });
            });
    });
}
```

and here is i'm calling this function with `then` and `catch`

```
getDataFromCouchBase(siteId).then((site) => {
    console.log(site);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

in case of wrong bucketName or the document not available in the bucket it crashes the server instead of thrown error being handled by the `catch` block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only time promises "handle" throws for you is in synchronous code inside the `new Promise` callback or in synchronous code in a `then` or `catch` callback. I don't know CouchBase, but I assume that `openBucket` callback is asynchronous, so it's completely outside the promise handling.

You want your commented-out code: `reject(err);`, not `throw err;`. It's more in keeping with what you're doing anyway.

Here's an analogue of your code using `setTimeout` to mimic the asynchronicity:

```
const getDataFromCouchBase = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            throw new Error("asynchronous throw");
        }, 0);
    });
}
getDataFromCouchBase()
    .then(r => {
        console.log("result:", r);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("error:", e.message);
    });
```

[Live on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=const%20getDataFromCouchBase%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22asynchronous%20throw%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%200)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0AgetDataFromCouchBase()%0A%20%20.then(r%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22result%3A%22%2C%20r)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22error%3A%22%2C%20e.message)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B)

Note how the `throw` isn't (and can't be) converted to a rejection for you. (It shows up in the actual web console [not Babel's pseudo-console, the actual one in devtools].)

It can be (and is) converted to rejection if the `throw` is *synchronous*:

```
const getDataFromCouchBase = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        throw new Error("synchronous throw");
    });
}
getDataFromCouchBase()
    .then(r => {
        console.log("result:", r);
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("error:", e.message);
    });
```

[Live copy on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=const%20getDataFromCouchBase%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Promise((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%22synchronous%20throw%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0AgetDataFromCouchBase()%0A%20%20.then(r%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22result%3A%22%2C%20r)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%0A%20%20.catch(e%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22error%3A%22%2C%20e.message)%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B)

Note how the `throw` is converted to a rejection for you. But in your case, I'm sure that callback is called asynchronously.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, that cleared few things :)

Comment: yes the callback was asynchronous. but I was under the impression that promise will handle the error throw there as well. my bad